# Manage a website gallery with dropbox folder

Tags: directory, dropbox, google-drive-api, image-gallery

I'm trying to make a gallery photo on website and my client need to upload these photos unto dropbox or google drive.

I've embed a gallery from google drive in my website and it works perfectly (which means I can see the photos). But, when I click on a photos, it redirects me on google drive and its not a good rendering.

I've also try this solution : [pull and display images in website gallery from dropbox directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282629/pull-and-display-images-in-website-gallery-from-dropbox-directory). It seems to be a good solution but unfortunatly, nothing appears on my website.

Anyone has a solution? I really need my client to manage himself is gallery photo without having to put it on FTP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Google Drive SDK and API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/), which allows you to get the list of files in a Drive folder and URLs that can be used to view the image directly. Depending on your needs, you can turn this into a gallery, use a lightbox to display the image, or whatever you specifically need.

You may also want to take a look at using Drive to [publish website content](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/publish-site). You may still need to write some code to create the gallery portion, but this provides an easy public place to store and manage the uploaded images.